# Issue related to admob android

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, android-service

I really don't know where to ask this questions? As it's related to admob.

1. Whether admob can be run in background running service?
2. Whether I can integrate both admob and appfload? is it illegal?
3. Under what basis clicks been calculated for interstital ads. Per click how much dollar  admob is paying?
4. As in my country, billing only available, what's the maximum dollar, Google will pay for me and how many days it will take?
5. Sometimes it's displaying same ads and sometimes it's displaying different ads. what will happen if user clicks same ads? will it affect my revenue?

   Will you please help me to sort out questions.

   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i can answer few of your questions:
2: If you want to add more that one add network use mediation by admobs. You can add multiple ad-network (whatever is supported by admobs. check the list).
3: interstitial are calculated on per impression basis (at-least that's for me). Banner ads are calculated on per click basis. It depends which country your user views the ads. to give a number anyway its $0.04 per click. Sometimes like $0.06 if the user installs the advertized app.
4: admobs pay on a net 30 basis. Minimum payout for admobs for ACH/ wire transfer is $100. Its $20 for a pay-pal transfer.
5: revenue will be calculated on each click. doesn't matter if user clicks on same ad.

Advice: Don't click your own ads (even to check the revenue). Don't ask friends to click.